# Is there any difference between the nouns "raise" and "rise"?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

I know the difference between the verbs to raise and to rise, but is there any difference between their corresponding nouns **raise** and **rise**?

For example, are the two sentences

> There was a gradual **raise** in the employment rate as the economy began to recover.
>
> There was a gradual **rise** in the employment rate as the economy began to recover.

both correct and do they have the same meaning?

The sentence is from an exercise where given a sentence and a word you have to complete another sentence so that it has similar meaning. The original sentence is:

> The employment rate rose gradually as the economy began to recover.

The word to use is *gradual* and the sentence to complete is:

> There ........... the employment rate as the economy began to recover.

So technically the solution with **rise** is the correct solution, but I was wondering if using **raise** changes the meaning.

Comment: The nouns raise and rise are used for salaries in AmE and BrE, respectively. However, that first sample sentence is wrong in both Englishes.

Comment: @Lambie Are the abbreviations AmE and BrE understandable in ELL? I know we use them in english.SE all the time, but I would think that we might want to spell them out in ELL.

Comment: @shoover Never had any complaints.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A "rise" is an increase in number, size, amount, or degree.

A "raise" is an *act* of increasing something.

*Rises* can happen naturally, or incrementally, such as a rise in temperature or a rise in unemployment. *Raises* are deliberate increases, such as raising someone's salary or raising an imposed limit.

If you look at the dictionary definition for *raise* as a noun you will see the definitions are all deliberate things:

- an increase in salary
- an increased stake in poker
- the action of lifting a weight over one's head

In your example of unemployment rates, "rise" would be the correct noun. The rates of unemployment have not been deliberately raised - the rise has just been observed.

It should be added that "rise" *is* sometimes used to describe an increase in pay, which as an intentional act by an employer does seem to be something of an exception to what I've just said. [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pay%20rise%2C%20pay%20raise&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpay%20rise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpay%20raise%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpay%20rise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpay%20raise%3B%2Cc0) shows that "pay raise" is used at least twice as much as "pay rise", still it is idiomatic. Still, as *verbs* the distinction is very clear and the link between usage of the verbs and the nouns is undeniable.

Comment: Indeed, historically, _raise_ is a causitive of _rise_.

Comment: Without the BrE/AmE discussion, this answer is not complete.

Comment: In AuE I think we use pay rise more than pay raise.  Also, the ngrams for payrise vs payraise (ie one word) show slightly higher for the former, but they're both so close to zero it doesn't matter.

Comment: @mcalex I think it is important to remember that the OP isn't simply about rises in pay. It is about the nouns rise vs raise in general. When it comes to the other example of unemployment rates, 'raised' is simply wrong - who raised it?

Comment: Er, from this side of the pond, that's not quite correct: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pay+rise%2Cpay+raise&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpay%20rise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpay%20raise%3B%2Cc0

Comment: What part of the UK are you from that you think "pay raise" is more common that "pay rise"?  I'm genuinely curious.  Or are you a non-brit who just happens to be in the UK at the moment?

Comment: _"The rates of unemployment have not been deliberately raised"_ Does it really have to be deliberate? If I set my couch on fire, the temperature in the room was raised by my actions; even if setting the couch on fire was an accident.

Comment: @flater That's a good point, but in your example there is direct cause and effect - the fire raised the temperature in the room. I accept that there could be causes attributable to rises in unemployment rates, but speaking as both a native English speaker AND a data analyst, it would be highly unusual to say that a calculated rate had 'raised'. Remember we're talking about these words as *nouns*, so it must be *highly specific*. Unless you can point to the action or cause that caused the rise, you can't really say "a raise".

Comment: Note that the words have meanings other than salary or economics.  E.g. "the house is built on a rise, so it has a good view".

Comment: @J... in BrE a salary increase is definitely "a raise" and not "a rise".

Comment: @J... Indeed I would define "a raise" as "a pay rise".

Comment: @OrangeDog Yes, but in the UK you will almost never hear anyone saying they got "a raise" or were "hoping for a raise", etc.  It's almost invariably that someone "gets a pay rise" or is "hoping for a pay rise", and when the phrase is shortened it usually keeps the same form (ie: "Ask for a rise", "got a rise"), implicitly "a rise [in pay]".  It's just odd to me that a Brit would not find it awkward to "ask for a raise", which is completely AmE.

Comment: @J... No, I've lived in the UK all my life and hear "a raise" and "hoping for a raise" all the time. Nobody has ever said "ask for a rise", or "got a rise" (meaning salary), both of which are weird and awkward.

Comment: @OrangeDog I find that honestly bizarre.  Do you work for an American multinational company, perhaps?  Or are you quite young? I lived in the UK for a long time and my experience was exactly the opposite, and every language reference I can find stands in agreement with that perspective, including the [rather prestigious dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/raise) that bears your city's name.  `Raise : noun[US] (UK : rise) - an increase in the amount that you are paid for the work you do`

Answer (score 15):

Personally, I think OP's first example is non-standard (particularly for Brits), because we usually use ***rise*** rather than ***raise*** as the noun form in such contexts (and [here's the proof](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20rise%20in%20interest%20rates%2Ca%20raise%20in%20interest%20rates&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20rise%20in%20interest%20rates%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20raise%20in%20interest%20rates%3B%2Cc0) of that, in an NGram chart). Offhand the only really common *noun* use I can think of for ***a raise*** is when it means ***a wage increase*** (that's in [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for%20a%20pay%20rise%2Cfor%20a%20pay%20raise&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20a%20pay%20rise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20a%20pay%20raise%3B%2Cc0) only - [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for%20a%20pay%20rise%2Cfor%20a%20pay%20raise&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20a%20pay%20rise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20a%20pay%20raise%3B%2Cc0) favours ***rise*** for that sense).

The other big difference is that as a *verb*, ***raise*** is usually *transitive* (you raise *something*, meaning you make it higher)<sup>1</sup>, whereas ***rise*** is usually *intransitive* (so we can just say *The tide is rising* - it's going up *itself*; it doesn't necessarily lift anything else).

---

For OP's final example text, we can include either term. For example,...

> 1: *There was a **rise** in the employment rate as the economy began to recover.*
>    2: *There was a **raised** employment rate as the economy began to recover.*

...where #1 reflects my initial assertion (prefer ***rise*** for the *noun* sense), and the somewhat less natural (but still syntactically valid) #2 is a "passive" Past Participle  of the transitive verb, used *adjectivally* (some unspecified agent raised the rate).

---

<sup>1</sup> As pointed out by [@Colin Fine](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/250201/is-there-any-difference-between-the-nouns-raise-and-rise/250209#comment470322_250204) above, and at greater length by [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/raise#:~:text=Raise%20is%20the%20causative%20of,are%20regular%3A%20Raise%20the%20window.),...

> ***Raise*** is the causative of **rise**; to **raise** something is to **cause it to rise**.
>   **Raise** is almost always used transitively.

Comment: + 1 This is the correct answer. AmE a raise (salary); BrE a rise (salary). Beyond that, both say rise for other matters. A rise in the unemployment rate.The first sentence from the OP is wrong is both Englishes!

Comment: @Lambie: The full OED includes **raise** noun definition 3a ***Chiefly U.S.** An increase in amount; an increase in the price, rate, value, etc., of something.* With citations such as *a gigantic raise in freight rates, a raise in prices, a raise in interest rate,...* Even in the US, ***rise*** is more likely in such contexts, but we can't really claim that ***raise*** is "wrong" when it's not (implicitly or explicitly) linked to ***wages***.

Comment: In the US, newspapers et alia simply do not say: a raise in price. **We say, like you, a price rise, a rise in prices**. For **wages**, in the US, we say raise, yes. In the UK, a rise. Of course, I am **repeating myself here**. I go by usage, and not by the OED here. a raise in the unemployment rate in AmE is non standard.

Comment: Transitive properties +1 for verbs.

Comment: Was going to add that ***raise*** is used in auctions and gambling, but the accepted answer already mentions poker.

Comment: There's also being obtuse, for example, to *get a rise* out of someone...

Comment: @J...Perhaps you mean abstruse.

Comment: @Lambie I've never heard anyone in the UK say they got "a rise" when their salary increases. It's always "a raise" or "a pay rise". Corporate vocabulary is largely American in origin.

Comment: @OrangeDog Oh boy. I never said it wasn't used in conjunction with another word. There is also wage rises in the UK.

Answer (score 3):

*Raise* requires an agent.  *Rise* does not (unless you're a magician or god).

What this means is that someone or something has to *raise* X, but X can *rise* by itself.

Also often there is the implication that X is being *held* by something or someone, if it is being *raised*.  With *rise*, the implication could be that it might be on a surface that is also moving up.

> There was a gradual RAISE in the employment rate as the economy began to recover.

Someone or something made it raise.  However since we can't identify that someone or something--the sentence is in the agentless passive voice--*rise* should be preferred.

Comment: So when I cook bread, it *rises* on it's own, and not because of the yeast?

Comment: The bread **rises**; the yeast is a **raising agent**.

Comment: @mcalex At that point the yeast is part of the bread.  Also, if you're going to be a pedant learn the difference between a contraction and a possessive.

Comment: Best answer on the page because it explains the difference in that raise as a verb requires an object.

Answer (score 1):

**[Raise](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raise#Noun)** is US English for "increase in wages or salary" like in

> The boss gave me a **raise**.

**[Rise](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rise#Noun)** is the noun derived from the verb *to rise* with all of the corresponding meanings, plus the UK English analog of the US **raise**.

> Exercise is usually accompanied by a temporary **rise** in blood pressure.

Anyway, irrespective of which variety of English your exercise is aimed at, it is **rise** which is needed there.